Formik not submit
Formik not submit the form when click at submit button. The handleSubmit() isn't being called, nether putting a console.log() or alert() directly at onSubmit.
I am using PrimeReact 10.8.3, React 18.3.1 and Formik 2.4.6.
Code:
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import signInMutation from "../apollo/schemas/mutations/signInUser";
import { Dialog } from "primereact/dialog";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
import { FloatLabel } from "primereact/floatlabel";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import { Password } from 'primereact/password';
import { ErrorContext } from "../../contexts/ErrorContext";

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
function SignIn({ show, handleClose }) {
    const cssInvalid = "[&>_*_.p-inputtext]:border-red-500 [&>_*_.p-inputtext]:border-[1px]";
    const [newUser, { loading }] = useMutation(signInMutation);
    const { setErrorMessage } = useContext(ErrorContext);

    async function handleSubmit(values) {
        try {
            const { data } = await newUser({
                variables: {
                    username: values.username,
                    email: values.email,
                    password: values.password,
                },
            });
            console.log(data.createUser);
            setErrorMessage(data.createUser);
            handleClose();
        } catch (error) {
            const errorMsg = error.graphQLErrors?.[0]?.message || "An error occurred";
            console.log(errorMsg);
            setErrorMessage(errorMsg);
        }
    }

    function handleValidation(values) {
        const errors = {};

        errors.email = false;
        errors.emailMessage = "";
        if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(values.email) && values.email !== "") {
            errors.email = true;
            errors.emailMessage = "Invalid email.";
        }

        errors.confirmPassword = false;
        errors.confirmPasswordMessage = "";
        if (values.password !== values.confirmPassword) {
            errors.confirmPassword = true;
            errors.confirmPasswordMessage = "Password not match.";
        }

        errors.username = false;
        errors.usernameMessage = "";
        if (values.username.length < 3 && values.username !== "") {
            errors.username = true;
            errors.usernameMessage = "Username must've more than 2 characters.";
        }
        if (values.username.length > 21 && values.username !== "") {
            errors.usernameMessage = "Username must've less than 21 characters.";
        }

        errors.password = false;
        errors.passwordMessage = "";
        if (values.password.length < 8 && values.password !== "") {
            errors.password = true;
            errors.passwordMessage = "Password must've more than 8 characters.";
        }
        if (values.password.length > 70 && values.password !== "") {
            errors.password = true;
            errors.passwordMessage = "Password must've less than 8 characters.";
        }

        return errors;
    }

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            email: "",
            username: "",
            password: "",
            confirmPassword: "",
        },
        onSubmit: (values) => handleSubmit(values),
        validate: (values) => handleValidation(values),
    });

    return (
        <>
            <Dialog
                visible={show}
                modal
                closable={!loading}
                onHide={handleClose}
                content={() => (
                    <div className="flex flex-col text-center items-center justify-center p-4 gap-4 bg-gradient-to-tr from-slate-700 rounded-xl">
                        <h1 className="select-none p-3 font-bold">EG</h1>
                        <form className="flex gap-7 flex-col p-4" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                            <div className={"flex flex-col " + (formik.errors.email ? cssInvalid : "")}>
                                <FloatLabel>
                                    <InputText
                                        type="email"
                                        name="email"
                                        invalid={formik.errors.email}
                                        required={true}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                        aria-describedby="email-help"
                                        className="p-3"
                                        value={formik.values.email} />
                                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                </FloatLabel>
                                <small
                                    id="email-help"
                                    className="text-red-300 select-none">
                                    {formik.errors.emailMessage}
                                </small>
                            </div>
                            <div className={"flex flex-col " + (formik.errors.username ? cssInvalid : "")}>
                                <FloatLabel>
                                    <InputText
                                        type="text"
                                        name="username"
                                        required={true}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                        aria-describedby="username-help"
                                        className="p-3"
                                        value={formik.values.username} />
                                    <label htmlFor="username">
                                        Username
                                    </label>
                                </FloatLabel>
                                <small
                                    id="username-help"
                                    className="text-red-300 select-none">
                                    {formik.errors.usernameMessage}
                                </small>
                            </div>
                            <div className={"flex flex-col " + (formik.errors.password ? cssInvalid : "")}>
                                <FloatLabel>
                                    <Password
                                        name="password"
                                        required={true}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                        invalid={formik.errors.password}
                                        className="[&>_*_.p-password-input]:p-3"
                                        value={formik.values.password}
                                        toggleMask />
                                    <label htmlFor="password">
                                        Password
                                    </label>
                                </FloatLabel>
                                <small
                                    id="confirmPassword-help"
                                    className="text-red-300 select-none">
                                    {formik.errors.passwordMessage}
                                </small>
                            </div>
                            <div className={"flex flex-col " + (formik.errors.confirmPassword ? cssInvalid : "")}>
                                <FloatLabel>
                                    <Password
                                        name="confirmPassword"
                                        required={true}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                        aria-describedby="confirmPassword-help"
                                        className="[&>_*_.p-password-input]:p-3"
                                        value={formik.values.confirmPassword}
                                        toggleMask />
                                    <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">
                                        Confirm Password
                                    </label>
                                </FloatLabel>
                                <small
                                    id="confirmPassword-help"
                                    className="text-red-300 select-none">
                                    {formik.errors.confirmPasswordMessage}
                                </small>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex align-items-center gap-2">
                                <Button
                                    label="Cancel"
                                    disabled={loading || formik.isSubmitting}
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={handleClose}
                                    text
                                    className="p-3 w-full text-primary-50 border-1 border-white-alpha-30 hover:bg-white-alpha-10" />
                                <Button
                                    label="Sing In"
                                    type="submit"
                                    loading={loading || formik.isSubmitting}
                                    text
                                    className="p-3 w-full text-primary-50 border-1 border-white-alpha-30 hover:bg-white-alpha-10" />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                )}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default SignIn;


I have tried put the form in Dialog body instead content, without Dialog,  tag with ,  with . Nothing is trowed in console.

Formik will not call handleSubmit when the fields are not fully validated (if you use the validate attribute), try removing the validate attribute and submit and you should validate with yup and validationSchema will be more effective and better.
